# AWS Glue hanging up & consuming lot of time in ETL job

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, etl, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue where I want to dump records from Oracle table (which has 80 million rows) to Redshift. However, almost 2 hrs go,it remains in hanging state & still nothing gets written to Amazon S3 & eventually I have to stop the job.

My code:

```
import sys
import boto3
import json
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

db_username = [removed]
db_password = [removed]
db_url = [removed]
table_name = [removed]
jdbc_driver_name = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
s3_output = [removed]

df = glueContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", db_url).option("user", db_username).option("password", db_password).option("dbtable", table_name).option("driver", jdbc_driver_name).load()

df.printSchema()


datasource0 = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "datasource0")
datasource0.schema()
datasource0.show()

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("correlation_id", "decimal", "correlation_id", "bigint"), ("machine_pin","varchar","machine_pin","varchar"),("messageguid","varchar","messageguid","varchar"), ("originating_domain_object_id", "decimal", "originating_domain_object_id", "bigint"), ("originating_message_type_id", "bigint", "originating_message_type_id", "bigint"), ("source_messageguid","varchar","source_messageguid","varchar"), ("timestamp_of_request","timestamp","timestamp_of_request","timestamp"),("token","varchar","token","varchar"),("id","decimal","id","bigint"),("file_attachment","decimal","file_attachment","bigint")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1,choice = "make_cols", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_jdbc_conf(frame = dropnullfields3, catalog_connection = "us01-isg-analytics", connection_options = {"dbtable": "analytics_team_data.message_details", "database": "jk_test"}, redshift_tmp_dir = "s3://aws-glue-scripts-823837687343-us-east-1/glue_op/", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")
```

When I use Apache Spark,it takes less than 1 hr to dump the data to Redshift.What modifications need to be required for performance optimization so that Glue dumps the data in a speedy manner?

Comment: How do you run it in spark? EMR? Do you tune it somehow? What's the parallelsm? How many executors do you use? Have you tried running the same code in Glue just without using the glueContext and using dataframe.write (or whatever you're using?).

Comment: Try to enable metrics (https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/07/aws-glue-now-provides-additional-ETL-job-metrics/) to have better understanding what's happening.